# How do I post a youtube video?

Tags: video

I have joined a charity and am responsible for updating their website. I have never used Expression Engine before only Wordpress sites for blogs, and I don't know how to post a youtube video on one of the web pages. Please help! Also if there is an Expression Engine guide I can get my hands on somehow that would be really useful.

Thanks,
Michelle

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert a video from YouTube using the same syntax you would on any other HTML page. However, if you would rather use a plugin to do such, DevDemon has a great, free add on named [Channel Videos].[1](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-videos) It may be a touch overkill for this need, but the question doesn't talk of needs much more than just adding a video. As for the docs, you can find them all on the EllisLab website.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Antenna - https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/antenna - is another useful addon for adding and outputting video data. It works by you adding the video URL to a custom field (or inside a Grid field). The template tag can then spit out the video along with various bits of meta data as required.